# How do I stop an LED Troffer flickering problem?

Tags: led, flashing

I am replacing 30 fluorescent troffer fixtures in my building with LED fixtures: [Lithonia Lighting GTL Series Recessed Troffer LED](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Lithonia-Lighting-GTL-Series-Recessed-Troffer-LED-Troffer-Actual-48-in-x-24-in-x-3-25-in/1001464750). These fixtures have led strips, no bulbs. Using a standard switch, no dimmers. Dedicated breaker, no other devices in circuit. Wiring lights in series. Testing after each light added. First light test works normally. Added second light, still normal. After adding third light, all three lights flash on and off randomly, every 5 to 10 seconds. After adding fourth, fifth  and sixth lights, all lights flash on and off randomly, but at a faster rate, every 2 to 4 seconds.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange.  Please show us a photo of the wiring in  your first troffer. You can [edit] your question to add it.  If you need to change devices, register your account by tying an email, Google or Facebook to it.  That way you can log in from any device.

Answer (score 1):

### So, your problem is that you are wiring lights in series.

This is not how you wire lights.

Single gets full voltage, works fine

Two in series, half voltage, apparently still works.

3 in series, 1/3 voltage, no worky.

4,5,6 in series, 1/4, 1/5, 1/6 voltage, no worky worse.

You are outing yourself as perhaps not actually qualified to be replacing lights, if you don't know (and evidently did not research) to wire them in parallel, as they are meant to be, so that each light gets full voltage as intended.

Comment: that's if he's using the term series correctly.

Comment: Yeah, ppl often confuse the terms, but from what the OP said, Ecnerwal is probably right.   Still...one would expect the OP to connect them in the same manner as the fixtures being replace. A wiring diagram and some pics would help a lot.

Comment: Yeah, LEDs only wire in series when you're dealing with raw emitters and driving them with a constant-current driver.